# Get raw EEG data from brainsense using python

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, brain-computer-interface

I have this BCI device: https://www.pantechsolutions.net/brainsense-bci

I want a python script to get the raw data coming from this sensor but i am not sure how to do it.

I have searched online but have found no good solution.

Please help.

Comment: Please give the links to the solutions you *have* found, and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: In the given link, they have modified the Mindflex device to get the raw data. But my device is different and also the datasheet of the chips used in the brainsense module is not available.    https://www.instructables.com/id/Mindflex-EEG-with-raw-data-over-Bluetooth/

Comment: I also saw some links of how to take bluetooth data with python but all of them are using sockets. I am not familiar with socket programming :(